# CMAKE MAC OSX library linking Issue: compiles on Linux but on on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker-errors, root-framework

I am trying to compile my code with CMake. But when I do the make command I get the following error:

```
[ 17%] Linking CXX shared library libglobal.so
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -dylib_install_name @rpath/libglobal.so -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 -o libglobal.so -L/opt/local/lib -L/Users/George/Documents/root/build/lib -lc++ -headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/global.dir/RawHitPeta6.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/CorrectedHit.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/CalibrationSettings.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/Coincidence.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/AnalysisSettings.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/Plot.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/Destination.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/Crystal.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/Geometry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/TwoModuleSetup.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/P6EvaluationBoard.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/SystemSingleLayer7.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/SystemSingleLayer8.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/SystemDualLayer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/SystemHighResolutionDualLayer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/global.dir/geometries/SystemHighResolutionDualLayerLong.cpp.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_Plot.cpp in Plot.cpp.o
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_Destination.cpp in Destination.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Analysis/global/libglobal.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Analysis/global/CMakeFiles/global.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I already looked for ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

```
This is the cmake outout I get: 

CMake Warning (dev):
Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   coincidencePlots
   correctedHitPlots
   generalPlots
   global
   processing
   rawHitPlots

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/George/Desktop/petaAnalysis/build
```

I already looked for ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). But I could not find anything useful, that helped.

This is the cmake output I get:

```
CMake Warning (dev):
Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
--help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
set the policy and suppress this warning.

MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

coincidencePlots
correctedHitPlots
generalPlots
global
processing
countRawPlots

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Hans/Desktop/Project/build
```

I tried to run the code on linux. There it seems works fine. I think it is a linking problem between the shared libraries I created.

This is are the CMAKE-files:
File 1(in main directory):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Analysis) 
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${Analysis_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)


SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++ -std=c++14 -m64 -I/Users/George/Documents/root/build/include")


#SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH true)
#SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/")
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin)

# Add MacPorts
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/opt/local/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/opt/local/lib)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Analysis)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(CrystalMapGenerator)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(CoincidenceBrowser)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(FunctionTests)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(AnalysisResultExtractor)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(AnalysisComparison)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(SDIPRawDataDebug)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(GateDataTimeCalibrationTester)
```

File 2(in subdirectory):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${Analysis_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()

#set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# Add information on ROOT libraries
INCLUDE(../FindROOT.cmake)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${ROOTSYS}/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${ROOTSYS}/lib)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(processing)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(generalPlots)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(rawHitPlots)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(correctedHitPlots)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(coincidencePlots)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(global)

include_directories("processing")
include_directories("generalPlots")
include_directories("rawHitPlots")
include_directories("correctedHitPlots")
include_directories("coincidencePlots")
include_directories("global")

set(SOURCES
    DataChain.cpp
    main.cpp
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(analysis ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(analysis processing generalPlots rawHitPlots correctedHitPlots coincidencePlots global ${ROOT_LIBRARIES} -lSpectrum -lMinuit)
```

File3(in folder of library global):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

INCLUDE(../../FindROOT.cmake)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${ROOT_INCLUDE_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${ROOT_LIBRARY_DIR})

ADD_LIBRARY(global SHARED
    RawHitPeta6.cpp
    CorrectedHit.cpp    
    CalibrationSettings.cpp
    Coincidence.cpp
    AnalysisSettings.cpp
    Plot.cpp
    Destination.cpp

    Crystal.cpp
    Geometry.cpp
    geometries/TwoModuleSetup.cpp
    geometries/P6EvaluationBoard.cpp
    geometries/SystemSingleLayer7.cpp
    geometries/SystemSingleLayer8.cpp
    geometries/SystemDualLayer.cpp
    geometries/SystemHighResolutionDualLayer.cpp
    geometries/SystemHighResolutionDualLayerLong.cpp
)
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: I'd bet that you're not linking to the correct library from ROOT that you need. You can use `make VERBOSE=1` to see the full compile/link commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of ROOT5 or ROOT6, instead of writing or downloading a `FindROOT.cmake`, use the info that ROOT auto-generates for you when your (or your package system) builds it.

In your ROOT installation, find the directory that holds `ROOTConfig.cmake`. Add that directory to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Then, call `find_package(ROOT)`.

A basic `CMakeLists.txt` could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)

execute_process(COMMAND root-config --prefix 
                COMMAND tr -d \\n
                RESULT_VARIABLE RC_RESULT 
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE ROOT_PREFIX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${ROOT_PREFIX}/share/root/cmake")
find_package(ROOT)

include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_print_variables(ROOT_FOUND ROOT_LIBRARIES ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Running `cmake` with that results in:

```
~/rt
❯ cmake .                                                   
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- ROOT_FOUND="1" ; ROOT_LIBRARIES="/usr/local/lib/root/libCore.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libImt.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libRIO.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libNet.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libHist.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libGraf.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libGraf3d.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libGpad.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libTree.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libTreePlayer.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libRint.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libPostscript.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libMatrix.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libPhysics.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libMathCore.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libThread.so;/usr/local/lib/root/libMultiProc.so" ; ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS="/usr/local/include/root"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/nega/rt

~/rt
❯
```

You'll notice that `ROOT_FOUND` has been set to `TRUE`, and `ROOT_LIBRARIES`, and `ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS` have been populated. You can now use those variables to setup your compilation and linking.

Comment: For completeness, the root project also provides instructions how root is meant to be used in cmake projects https://root.cern.ch/how/integrate-root-my-project-cmake

Comment: Hi nega and pseyfert. Thank yout alot for helping me.

I tried to include your changes. But I still get the same error.

I included the output I got from the commangs nega suggested and put them in: SET(SET(ROOT_LIBRARIES="/Applications/root_v6.12.06/lib/libCore.so;....) and SET(ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS="/Applications/root_v6.12.06/include"). But I have still the same error. I am linking them wrong ?

Comment: Use the variables directly. Don't extract the values from them and set new variables. After successfully running `find_package(ROOT)` you get `ROOT_FOUND` `ROOT_LIBRARIES` and `ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS`. Use those variables in your calls to `include_directories()` or `target_include_directories()`, `add_library()`, and `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: I added this line to cmake. INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${ROOTSYS_INCLUDE_DIRS}) and also target_link_libraries(analysis ${ROOT_LIBRARIES}) and still have the problem . I don't know if the problem is from root. Because i wrote another file to test the root libraries and there it seems to compile fine.

Comment: I think I found the core of the problem. I tried several builds. And the only time I have this problem, is when I add some root function to a shared library. add_libray(libname SHARED libcontents.cpp) in in libcontents.cpp is a root function, it can't compile. But if i take it out and out the root function as an example in the main.cpp, then it compiles just fine. How can I "show" the shared library(that is found in a subdirectory), where the rootlibraries are ?

Comment: `add_library(mylib mylib.c mylib2.c)` followed by `target_link_libraries(mylib ${ROOT_LIBRARIES})`. See the docs for [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) and [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)